# What is the usefulness of diagonalise a Fisher matrix?

Tags: diagonalization, covariance, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

In Statistics, we often talk about diagonalising the Covariance matrix (like in Principal Analysis Components) but what would be the interest and the usefulness of diagonalising the Fisher matrix : How could I exploit this diagonal matrix ?

Initially, I thought that it would allow me to do cross-correlations between 2 Fisher matrix by summing the 2 diagonalised matrix and doing the sum to get an estimator $\sigma_{\hat{\tau}}$ on each parameter :

$$\dfrac{1}{\sigma_{\hat{\tau}}^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}$$

But it doesn't give the expected gain for the constraints on parameters.

So, I wonder if there are other utilities to perform these diagonalisations on Fisher matrix (with a preference for carrying out cross-correlations if possible).

Any help/suggestion/clue/remark is welcome.

Comment: Under certain regularity conditions, the [inverse Fisher information is the covariance matrix of the asymptotic distribution of the maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency), so diagonalizing the Fisher information can be interpreted as diagonalizing a covariance matrix in this special case.

Comment: @angryavian . Thanks for your answer. What is your opinion about setting weights on each diagonal elements of the 2 matrices to represent the proportion of information brought by each of the 2 Fisher matrices. The method of "Pooled matrix" suggests me to take an average of the diagonal elements to build a representative global diagonal matrix . Then I could build a final matrix by doing : $Fisher_\text{final}=P_1.D.P_1^{-1}+P_2.D.P_2^{-1}$. Your knowledge about this topic could help me. Regards